# Direction for greatest derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Suppose I have a function like $f(x,y) = e^x e^y x^2 y^2$, and I want to know in which direction the derivative will grow fastest at a stationary point.

$(0,0)$ is a stationary point of the example formula and the direction in which the gradient grows fastest is $(1,1)$ (or $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ when we normalize the direction vector).

Is there a method for finding the direction in which the gradient grows fastest analytically for any function?
How would I go about doing such a thing?

Should I look at the third order derivatives?

Answer (score 1):

You have a function $f(x,y)$ and you know that $\nabla f(x_0,y_0)=0$, that is, this is a stationary point, but the methodology is general. The second derivative matrix is $\nabla^2 f(x,y)$, and applying it to a vector will give the rate of change of the gradient in that direction.

Because of the symmetry of partial derivatives, the matrix $\nabla^2 f(x,y)$ is symmetric, and as so, diagonalizable. That means that you can get the direction of fastest changing as the eigenvector connected to the eigenvalue of greatest magnitude.

Comment: The Hessian matrix (matrix of second derivatives) is zero everywhere at $(0,0)$ for the given example function. Have I chosen a bad exmaple?

Comment: It is not a bad example, just one where there is no preferential direction for changing.

Comment: Suppose we have a univariate function, and consider a minimum as stationary point. Then the second order derivative is always positive and so it will not give the direction in which the gradient will change the fastest. Maybe I should have been more clear that I am talking about absolute growth.

Comment: If you have an univariate function, then you only have one direction, that of the variable, and this is an eigenvector. The fact that you want absolute growth is related to take the eigenvalue of greatest magnitude, and not greatest value.

Comment: For a univariate function there are two directions from the stationary point, the direction of increasing and the direction of decreasing the variable. Supposing your method provides me with the axis along which the gradient changes most, how do I know whether I have to increase or decrease along that axis?

Comment: You get is by the sign of the eigenvalue.

Comment: At a minimum, the Hessian is positive-definite, and so all eigenvalues are positive. The sign of the eigenvalue doesn't provide information here.